# Erro ao inserir dados no banco PHP PDO

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

Estou tentando criar um novo cadastro no banco com o seguinte código e retorna o erro:
Insert value list does not match column list ou os o registro é criado mas em branco, sendo que os campos são NOT NULL, já tentei outras opções aqui no forum e nada.

Já pesquisei, refiz e nada.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="center-block form-novo-cad">
    <form method="post" action="novoCadSend.php">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Nome:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="telefone">Telefone:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telefone">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="endereco">Endereço:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="endereco">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6  col-sm-6    col-md-6    col-lg-6" style="margin-left: -15px;">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="numero">Número:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="numero">
        </div>
      </div><br><br><br><br>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="bairro">Bairro:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bairro">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="cidade">Cidade:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cidade">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Criar Cadastro</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
//novoCadSend.php
// inclui o arquivo de inicialização
require 'init.php';

// resgata variáveis do formulário
$name = isset( $_POST[ 'name' ] ) ? $_POST[ 'name' ] : '';
$email = isset( $_POST[ 'email' ] ) ? $_POST[ 'email' ] : '';
$telefone = isset( $_POST[ 'telefone' ] ) ? $_POST[ 'telefone' ] : '';
$endereco = isset( $_POST[ 'endereco' ] ) ? $_POST[ 'endereco' ] : '';
$numero = isset( $_POST[ 'numero' ] ) ? $_POST[ 'numero' ] : '';
$bairro = isset( $_POST[ 'bairro' ] ) ? $_POST[ 'bairro' ] : '';
$cidade = isset( $_POST[ 'cidade' ] ) ? $_POST[ 'cidade' ] : '';

$PDO = db_connect();
try {
  $PDO->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
  $stmt = $PDO->prepare( 'INSERT INTO users VALUES(:name, :email, :telefone, :endereco, :numero, :bairro, :cidade)' );
  $stmt->execute( array(
    //':id'   => $id,
    ':name' => $name,
    ':email' => $email,
    ':telefone' => $telefone,
    ':endereco' => $endereco,
    ':numero' => $numero,
    ':bairro' => $bairro,
    ':cidade' => $cidade,
  ) );
  echo $stmt->rowCount();
} catch ( PDOException $e ) {
  echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Explicando:

Como a mensagem de erro já diz, o problema é que você não está especificando os nomes das colunas no *insert*.

Para fazer o *insert* numa tabela sem especificar as colunas, deve colocar os campos na sequência que a tabela está definida, mas como você quer ignorar a coluna `id` (que provavelmente é auto-incrementada), deve obrigatoriamente especificar os nomes das colunas.

Veja este exemplo:

Tabela **usuarios**

```
id  | nome
```

Posso fazer o insert da seguinte forma:

```
INSERT INTO usuarios 
VALUES (1, 'Fulano');
```

Mas se não quero informar o `id` sou obrigado a fazer assim:

```
INSERT INTO usuarios (nome)
VALUES ('Fulano');
```

---

## Resolvendo o seu problema:

Se o nome das suas colunas no banco de dados é o mesmo nome das variáveis, substitua a linha:

```
$stmt = $PDO->prepare( 'INSERT INTO users VALUES(:name, :email, :telefone, :endereco, :numero, :bairro, :cidade)' );
```

Por:

```
$stmt = $PDO->prepare( 'INSERT INTO users (name, email, telefone, endereco, numero, bairro, cidade) VALUES(:name, :email, :telefone, :endereco, :numero, :bairro, :cidade)' );
```

> Ou como o [rray](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/91/rray) falou
>   apenas descomente o id e coloque como *null*.

Comment: Dependendo da configuração da tabela/auto-increment você pode passar o valor do id como null que o banco se vira.

Comment: Não sabia dessa! (Y)

Comment: A minha dificuldade está sendo como passar esses dados sendo que recebo eles via post.

Comment: Coloque o nome das colunas no *insert* ou coloque o `id` como *null*, isso deve resolver o problema.

Comment: Agora criou um novo registro na tabela mas todos os dados vazio, sendo que os registros estão como NOT NULL.
Aconteceu com ou sem o id.

Comment: Coloque o nome das colunas então, eu editei a resposta. Veja a linha que deve substituir, só confira se os nomes das colunas estão corretos.